# Netsuite send an email alert for picking tickets that need to be printed

Tags: netsuite

There has to be a better way than having to keep refreshing the print picking ticket page.
I want to get an email alert when a new picking ticket needs to be printed. We do not have WMS or any third-party add-on.

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with "Picking Tickets"; however I might be able to assist if you share with me the url from when you view this page in the UI.  The url should contain the record internal id before ".nl?".

Comment: https://4973726.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/print/printform.nl?printtype=pickingticket&trantype=salesord&method=print&title=Picking+Tickets&whence=#

Answer (score 0):

Given the url you specified (...accounting/print/printform.nl?**printtype=pickingticket**&**trantype=salesord**&method=print&title=Picking+Tickets&whence=#) the picking status (whether or not one needs to be printed) seems to be tied to Sales Orders.  Creating a Transaction saved search and enabling emails to be sent with attached results should meet your requirements.

Saved search criteria:
Type = Sales Order 
Main Line = true
To Be Printed = true **OR** Printed Picking Ticket = false (depending on your use case)

Results:
Add all the column data you'd like to see.  If you want to include a link to print the actual ticket.  Navigate to the print screen in the UI and take note of the url, it is likely standard url with "&id=XXX" to specific which record to print.  You can created the following Formula (Text) to house the url = '<a href=https://XXXX.netsuite.com/....?id='|| {internalid} ||''

Reference [Answer Id 8487](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8487/kw/8487) for more on Saved search Emails.

Comment: I was able to create one close however drop shipment keep showing up /                       
        I tried a couple of ways and keep getting ERROR: Invalid Expression '<a href=https: //XXXXX.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/print/NLSPrintForm.nl?printtype=pickingticket&trantype=salesord&method=print&hotprint=T&title=Sales+Orders&whence={internalid} ||''

Comment: I believe drop ship is designated at the item level.  So you could add search criteria such as "Item fields... Drop Ship Item is false"

Comment: everything tried and still pulls the drop ships  FILTER
DESCRIPTION
FORMULA
Type is Sales Order  
Main Line is true  
Date is not before 8/1/2021  
Status is none of Sales Order:Pending Billing, Sales Order:Billed, Sales Order:Cancelled, Sales Order:Closed  
Drop Ship? (Custom Column) is false  
Printed Picking Ticket is false  
Applied To Link Type is not Drop Shipment  
PO Type (Custom Body) is not Drop Ship